file_get_contents() request fails online (but not in localhost)
I have a code that worked on my website just fine until now and I can't find why. However the code still works in localhost. It's a file_get_contents() request to download a PDF file from another website.
Here's the code:
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);



$Today = date('d/m/Y');
$Subscriber = getSubscriber($_GET['ID']);
// $ChildrenCount = countChildren($_GET['ID']);
$Children = getChildren($_GET['ID']);
$childrenNames = '';
foreach ($Children as $Child) { $childrenNames .= $Child['last_name'].' '.$Child['first_name'].' ('.$Child['birth_date'].'), '; }
$Organization = getMainOrganization();
$Domiciliation = getCurrentDomiciliation($_GET['ID']);
$FirstDomiciliation = getFirstDomiciliation($_GET['ID']);
// Keep numbers only
$Organization['approval_number_edited'] = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $Organization['approval_number']);
$Organization['address'] = $Organization['address_1'].', '.$Organization['address_2'];
$Subscriber['full_name'] = $Subscriber['last_name'] . ' ' .$Subscriber['maiden_name'];
$Subscriber['address'] = $Organization['address_1'].', BP '.$Subscriber['id_subscriber'].', '.$Organization['address_2'];


// ------------------------------------  CERFA GENERATOR (CERFA n°16030_01)


// Set the URL and Request Data
$url = 'https://www.service-public.fr/simulateur/calcul/16030';
// $cookie = 'TS012e9d3d=012a7f58e0510196f8d63905db5cf348d774c546381e234b911ab924db908bb77c41e03de1d9fd2128b821e7e153334d50aeacc2b670729b6415fe1c71c341e6ec61375d8646e62b730c34d848d8d09dbfaaa0499e916a6641b0aaff16072de0072c2a12ee; SP_SESSION=b0f08d7c-434d-47b0-bb25-609c16b56a67; TS01425d24=012a7f58e0c43d92f9b240f61a0bcffb4c7f129daaf905b18e991e299553e6a313f30cb4cf3f6e5090062e4fe1bb1a420be7c9d5d1a96620bf9e6c381d0c623edf88bfb628';
$cookie = 'TS012e9d3d=012a7f58e03c704a73b06a61a6cefcd6c55d5ccca0d6bcf732f604e0a3e8202ea069746df55e0201c5cf1639444036d7585f8a45331bada6ae9bb01ceffa7d8941d8f503df; SP_SESSION=4fa36d41-70b6-4783-91f0-5aa125bd0b64; TS01425d24=012a7f58e02433404b9d3a707d451569e154d70e35d6bcf732f604e0a3e8202ea069746df5800e4b9bd82402623c56fb5169101a5a504ca089a8d41fa0fef524c89a6d3d12';

$data = [
  'renseignement_identite_sexe' => ($Subscriber['sex'] == 1) ? 'm' : 'f',
  'renseignement_identite_nom' => $Subscriber['full_name'],
  'renseignement_identite_prenom' => $Subscriber['first_name'],
  'renseignement_identite_date_naissance' => $Subscriber['birth_date'],
  'renseignement_identite_lieu_naissance' => $Subscriber['birth_country'],
  'renseignement_identite_infos_ayants_droit' => rtrim($childrenNames, ', '),
  'renseignement_organisme_nom' => $Organization['name'],
  'renseignement_organisme_election_domicile' => 'Clermont-Fd',
  'renseignement_organisme_responsable' => $Organization['manager'],
  'renseignement_organisme_prefecture' => $Organization['approval_prefecture_name'],
  'renseignement_organisme_numero_agrement' => $Organization['approval_number_edited'],
  'renseignement_organisme_adresse' => $Organization['address'],
  'renseignement_organisme_courriel' => $Organization['email'],
  'renseignement_organisme_telephone' => $Organization['phone_number'],
  'renseignement_adresse_nom' => $Subscriber['full_name'],
  'renseignement_adresse_prenom' => $Subscriber['first_name'],
  'renseignement_adresse_adresse' => $Subscriber['address'],
  'attestation_date_validite_debut' => $Domiciliation['starting_date'],
  'attestation_date_validite_fin' => $Domiciliation['ending_date'],
  'attestation_date_1ere_domiciliation' => $FirstDomiciliation['starting_date'],
  'signature_lieu' => 'Clermont-Ferrand',
  'signature_date' => $Today,
  'step' => '1',
  '_csrf_token' => '5RCIIAqQa43tGsiActNIpGhEudu2hsgYMZRYXzX-P3o',
  'telechargement' => '1'
];

$url .= '?' . http_build_query($data);

// Get the response using file_get_contents
$response = file_get_contents($url);

if ($response === false) {
    // Handle error
    echo "Error fetching response.";
    exit;
}

// Output file name and path
$Cerfa = 'cpp-cerfa-id-'.$Subscriber['id_subscriber'];

// Create a new PDF file
$file = fopen($Cerfa, 'w');
// Write the content into the PDF file
fwrite($file, $response);
// Close the file
fclose($file);

// Set the appropriate header to indicate it's a PDF file
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');

// Set the Content-Disposition header to display the PDF inline in the browser
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$Cerfa.'"');

// Output the file content
echo $response;

// Delete the generated PDF file from the server
unlink($Cerfa);
?>


Here's the error I get:

array(2) { ["error"]=> string(60) "SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104" ["errno"]=> int(56) }

It works in localhost and also using Insomnia (API Client for REST).
I'm able to get a correct response and download the PDF file I should get.
I've spent nights trying to understand…

I don't see any use of curl in the PHP script. Do you mean file_get_contents($url)?

Googling SSL error 56 indicates that this usually means the request is being blocked by a firewall or proxy. Maybe the website is blocking your hosting service, or your hosting service has a firewall blocking it.

@Barmar yes sorry for the confusion,  it's file_get_contents($url)...

@Barmar Yes , that's what I see also while googling the SSL error 56. but I can't find how to fix that. I'm new to developing and servers... From what I can remember I didn't touch the firewall at all. The only thing that changed before the code stops to work as expected is my .htaccess file, but I don't know if that could cause problems to this code. And if so no idea what and how to fix it... could you help more plz ?

@KJ It's because I don't just need the file downloaded. I need it automatically filled with the info I send (php script) before I download it... Just like the file I would get if I go to the url and fill the form and download the file...

I'm sorry if I'm not clear enough, I'm new to all this but I'll try :
When you visit the url the website has a form to be filled in order to download the pdf file with the info you provided. What I did is look at the inspector to see how I can replicate that automatically with a script from my own website. So I'm trying  to get the pdf file with the info I provide each time

@KJ but it works fine in localhost but not live
